# How to use Git login credentials from Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a git repository running on linux connected to LDAP.  I have a jenkins installation on Windows.  I was able to set up a job to connect to the git repository.  The job correctly detects the changes of my repository.

The problem is that nothing is downloaded on the Windows machine that is running Jenkins.  I suppose I need to run a git pull so that I have the code downloaded from the linux server to my Windows box.

Jenkins plug-in has the login information stored to access the repository. But if I simply run 'git pull' from the batch file in my Jenkins job I need login and password.

How to make Jenkins use that login and password?

Comment: I would try setting ssh access, so I could be able to add my public ssh key on the server and never be prompted for user and password.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion but considering that Jenkins plug-in has the login information stored to access the repository, I was wondering if there was a way to use them to get the updates files.

Comment: GitHub also works with tokens. Maybe there's a setting in Jenkins to use a token? https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: When you say "the job correctly detects the changes of my repository", I assume you're using the Git Plugin? If so, your repository should be automatically checked-out. If not, that's either a bug or a strange misconfiguration. What does your job config look like, and what is the output of the build?

Comment: Yes, I am using the git plugin.  I connected the job directly to the server repository on the linux box.  Jenkins is running the Job on a Windows box.  The job currently is not running anything because there is no code on the Windows box.  I thought the plugin would ask me for a directory where it would save the code. Maybe I am missing something here. How do I get the changes from he central repository into my local Windows box?